# How to have XnView MP open images in browse mode, rather than fullscreen mode, when opening images from outside XnVew MP?

Tags: application-launch, image-viewer, xnview

When opening XnView MP via an image (e.g. drag & drop or double-clicking the image), it opens in fullscreen mode, rather than windowed mode. How can XnView MP be configured instead to open the image in a tabbed window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the "Mode when starting with a file" setting.

1. Open settings.

   - MS Windows & Linux: Tools → Settings
   - OS X: XnView → Preferences…
2. Open the "General" group on the left pane.
3. Open the "General" tab on the right (which should open by default).
4. In the "Startup" section, set "Mode when starting with a file" to "Normal".

Comment: Now in version 0.97.0, there's another option "browser", which may cater to your need better.

Comment: @DavidH.J.: the newer mode isn't quite what I was looking for, though it took the name. Thanks for the thought, though.